# How to phrase "You know what they say? [quote]" in Chinese?

Tags: translation, phrase

When giving some kind of saying or folklore knowledge, in English we often say e.g.:

> You know what they say?  Two heads are better than one.

I want to say something similar in Chinese:

> You know what they say?  天不怕地不怕，就怕老外说中国话！

I find this an amusing rhyme, and it usually gets a laugh.  However, I'm not sure what to preface it with.  [YouDao](http://youdao.com/example/blng/eng/you_know_what_they_say) uses semi-literal translations:

> 你知道他们说...
> <sub>Nǐ zhīdào tāmen shuō...</sub>
>
> 你知道他们怎么说...
> <sub>Nǐ zhīdào tāmen zěnme shuō...</sub>

But I don't know if this is actually used by Chinese speakers (outside of translations from English).  Perhaps it's Engnese (reverse Chinglish) to say this, and there's a more appropriate phrase in Chinese.

**Question**: How to phrase "You know what they say? [quote]" in Chinese?

Comment: iciba: you know what they say, 

Cindy: Well, you know what they say . All great minds think alike!

嗯, 你知道的. 俗话说: 英雌所见略同!

2.

Well, you know what they say: Be careful what you wish for.

你知道他们总是说: “要小心你内心希望的. ”

3.

But you know what they say : beauty is only skin - deep.

实际上,她比谁都刻薄和小气. ”  & more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

你知道他们说的什么吗

你知道他们怎么说吗

are common phrases， but not for this context。

Depends on the type of the quote， you can use

俗话说/老话说/有句话叫：folk saying

古语有云 （classical saying）

X曰 （quote from ancient scholar）

XX说 （common phrase）

A: 俗话说： 三个臭皮匠， 顶一个诸葛亮（Two heads are better than one）

B：有句话叫： 人多手乱。

A：古人云：多多益善。

B：子曰：你说得不对。

A: 高尔基说： 子没说过。

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there's an equivalent expression:

-俗话说得好[quote]

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

**常言道**

> chángyándào

*ABC*

> F.E.
> as the saying goes
>
> 常言道, 熟能生巧。
> Chángyándào, shúnéngshēngqiǎo.
> As the saying goes, practice makes perfect.

Which could just as easily be translated as: You know what they say, practice makes perfect.

Answer (score 0):

W can split this into several scenario.

If u want to say or quote Something: 俗話說、俗話話、古語有云。

It u want to say question your audience to understand what the third party say:

你明佢地講乜，你明白其他人說什麼